# Is it possible to create Xamarin Forms App(Android and iOS) using Bluetooth GATT/GAP in BLE v5.0?

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

GATT/GAP can work in iOS using Xamarin Forms?

or we need MFi chip for that ?

Anyone can please help on this.

Comment: I mean you should be asking this to Apple, If iOS supports this, you can do it in XF or Maui or Flutter or whatever cross-platform tool you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Core Bluetooth framework in iOS, [Core Bluetooth framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth?language=objc) provides the classes needed for your apps to communicate with BLE wireless technology. Note that to access Core Bluetooth APIs on apps linked on or after iOS 13, include the NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key. In iOS 12 and earlier, include NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription to access Bluetooth peripheral data. For writing to GATT server, you can refer to [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771932/why-im-getting-pairing-request-dialog-in-ios-for-ble-after-write-operation-in-x#:%7E:text=This%20is%20my%20code%20where%20I%27m%20connecting%20and%20writing%20to%20GATT%20server)